# Simple question of limit of 3-variable-functions

Tags: limits

> Evaluate the limits, or explain why the limit fails to exist.
>
> 1. $$\text{lim}_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (0,0,0)}\frac{2x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$
> 2. $$\text{lim}_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (0,0,0)}\frac{xy-xz+yz}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$

In 2-variable cases, I know that I can covert the function into polar coordinates and try to find the limit when $r$ tends to $0$. Similarly, I can make use of the spherical and cylindrical coordinates. But it seems that they don't work here. Any hints on tackling these two problems will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the definition for the limits: $f(\bar{x})\to 0$ as $\bar{x}\to 0$ if
for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $\delta>0$ s.t. $|\bar{x}|<\delta$ implies
$|f(\bar{x})|<\epsilon$. In particular the limit should be the same from any direction. In short you can show that a limit does not exist by approaching $0$
from different directions and showing that the limits are not the same.

For 1.: Try approaching zero from the coordinate axels, e.g.
$$
\lim_{(x,0,0)\to 0}\frac{2x^2+3y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^2}{x^2}=2.
$$

For 2.: Try approaching zero from lines $(x,x,0)$ and $(0,0,z)$.